# Mouse/Touch coordinates in cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to get the xy coordinates for where I click, or better yet where the mouse pointer is, so that I can convert them into char and display them on the screen, and I remember something in hellolua throwing coordinates of clicks and movements while clicked as touch movements into the console, so I thought maybe I could do something similar in cpp with the cctouch command getLocationInView();, and this is what I did.
In init, I declare

```
setTouchEnabled(true);
```

and where I'm trying to get the touch coordinates i use

```
CCTouch pTouch;
CCPoint p = pTouch.getLocationInView();
p = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->convertToGL(p);
float x = p.x;
float y = p.y;
```

However it's not working as I'd expect it to work. Does anyone know how to get the mouse/touch coordinates to return accurately in cocos2d-x(cpp)?

Edit : Sorry I should have clarified, I'm working on a windows 7 desktop in a VisualStudio express environment, and I want this project to be cross platform. The hellolua application that was in the samples had it that the mouse clicks would throw touch event begins and ends with coordinates into the console, even though I was using my mouse. This is why I was hoping I could do something similar in CPP, except have the coordinates printed on the screen. However using this code, I would get static values for x and y, which wouldn't change no matter where I clicked.

Comment: what DO you expect? How is it different from what you expect? Mind-reading has not been invented yet. ;)

Comment: ps: don't mention mouse/click, it's confusing, made me think you're making a desktop app

Comment: Sorry, I clarified my working environment and expectations in the edit.

Comment: Have tried same code on OS X & iOS simulator or newest version of cocos2d-x? This should be a platform related issue. If you can't find where it is, report this on cocos2d-x forum.

Answer (score 2):

try this code:

```
bool PickCard::ccTouchBegan(CCTouch* touch, CCEvent* event)
{
    CCPoint touchLocation = touch->getLocationInView();
    touchLocation = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->convertToGL( touchLocation );
    touchLocation=convertToNodeSpace(touchLocation);
    CCLOG(" TouchLocation X=%f TouchLocation Y=%f",touchLocation.x,touchLocation.y);
}
```

Comment: wouldn't think just go back and forth between GL and UI spaces?

Comment: touch->getLocation() returns the point in GL coordinates so you can skip the GL conversion and just call convertToNodeSpace(touch->getLocation())